# Laravel 5.2 подключить свои классы или функции для вызова в контроллере

Tags: laravel

Как правильно подключить свои классы не являющиеся моделями laravel для использования в контроллере?
Это может быть совокупность классов, или даже просто функции, в общем нужен аналог require_once что бы не писать все в контроллере, но и не наследовать классы от Model, вот так:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Code extends Model
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это реализуется через сервис-провайдер http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/providers (более правильно)

====

А можно так (топорно):

Копируем нужный нам файлик с классом и нужными функциями в папку app

Допустим app/Code.php, добавляем файлик в неймспейс namespace App; (перед описанием класса)

Регистрируем в секции aliases наш класс

```
'Code'          => \App\Code::class,
```

Теперь в контроллере:

```
$Code = new Code;
$Code::метод
$Code->метод
```